# How to create a email template with cart products - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, module, email, email-templates

How to create an email template with cart products, I want to create my own module with cart products and want to send the mail to the admin. How can I do this please educate with brief note.

**Thanks in Advance :)**

Comment: When press add to cart button then mail send to admin ? Please describe more your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to create custom module you have to observer for `place order` event. (you can use this event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`). And in this observer you will get all products in cart and you can send email from this place. follow this link: [send email](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-send-email-in-magento-2/). In `events.xml` use above event instead of `customer_register_success`.

**EXAMPLE:**
**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action"> <!--place order-->
        <observer name="vendor_observer_place_order" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\PlaceOrder" />
    </event>
 </config>
```

**PlaceOrder.php**

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use HostAdvice\EmailDemo\Helper\Email;
    class PlaceOrder implements ObserverInterface
    {
        private $helperEmail;

        public function __construct(
            Email $helperEmail
        ) {
            $this->helperEmail = $helperEmail;
        }
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            return $this->helperEmail->sendEmail();
        }
```

Comment: how i will run this session when i click button the mail should be send

Answer (score 0):

> Create plugin for send email when add to cart process

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
        <plugin name="add_email_before_add_to_cart" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app\code\VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart**

**Add.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

class Add   
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
            //add You required logic to send email 
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***