# How to show the cart products in email template - Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3, cart, email, email-templates, quoteitem

How to show the cart products in the email template i can't loop into email template, and i can't pass the products into email template, I want send mail with the current cart products so I'am working it but i can't show the car products.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a email template with cart products - Magento 2.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/306514/how-to-create-a-email-template-with-cart-products-magento-2-3)

Comment: That was not working and there is no reply for it.

Comment: @RakeshDonga i want to send a mail like rfq process so if customer click submit the mail should sent to admin or seller for that i want all cart products